# copy text to clipboard through temporary <input>

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript, I create `input`, fill it with data, and want to copy `value` to the clipboard. Unfortunately, nothing is copied. Why this way does not work properly?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Copy test</title>
    <style>html{background: #000;}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="testButton">Copy</button>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            let button = document.getElementById('testButton');

            button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                let el = document.createElement('input');

                // fill input with values
                el.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                el.setAttribute('value', 'text to copy');

                // try to copy
                el.select();
                document.execCommand('copy');

                console.log("OK");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API not widely supported by browsers, so maybe it's a reason.
I would suggest you to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/clipboard instead and you won't need to think about cross-browser stuff.

If you still want to use your code, so i guess it happening because you didn't append this element to the DOM.

Working snippet:

```
 button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            let el = document.createElement('input');

            document.body.appendChild(el);

            // fill input with values
            el.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            el.setAttribute('value', 'text to copy');
            // try to copy
            el.select();
            document.execCommand('copy');
            el.remove()
            console.log("OK");
        });
```

Comment: I used Google Chrome 77.0.3865.90

Comment: Then i guess it's because you didn't append it to the DOM